# How to create GUI can fit in any screen resolution using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, user-interface

anyone can help me how to fix this GUI?
I created a GUI, then I need the GUI can fit to any screen size without any size change.
This script, when I execute in other computer with different resolution, the size changed.

Please help me. Thank you

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog"
$Width = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens.bounds.width
$Heigt = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens.bounds.height

$Widht_Form = $Width[0] / 3.5
Write-Host "$Widht_Form"
$Heigt_Form = $Heigt[0] / 1.8
Write-Host "$Heigt_Form"
$Form.Width = $Widht_Form
$Form.Height = $Heigt_Form

$label1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'
$Yes = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
$No = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
$Title = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'
$timer1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer'
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState'

$Form_Load = {  
    $TotalTime = 10 #in seconds
        $script:StartTime = (Get-Date).AddSeconds($TotalTime)
        #Start the timer
        $timer1.Start()
}   
$Cancel_Click={ 
}
$timer1_Tick={
        #Use Get-Date for Time Accuracy
        [TimeSpan]$span = $script:StartTime - (Get-Date)
        #Update the display
        $Form.Text = $label1.Text = "{0:N0}" -f $span.TotalSeconds
        if ($span.TotalSeconds -le 0) {
            $timer1.Stop()
            $Form.Close()
        }
    }

$Form_StateCorrection_Load=
{
    $Form.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
}

$Form_Cleanup_FormClosed=
{
    try
    {
        # $Cancel.remove_Click($Cancel_Click)
        $Form.remove_Load($Form_Load)
        $timer1.remove_Tick($timer1_Tick)
        $Form.remove_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
        $Form.remove_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
    }
    catch [Exception]
    { }
}

$Form.SuspendLayout()
$Form.Controls.Add($label1)
$Form.Controls.Add($Yes)
$Form.Controls.Add($No)
$Form.Controls.Add($Title)

$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form.BackColor = "#f6f6f6"
$Form.add_Load($Form_Load)

$label1.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,20,style=Bold'
$Label1.ForeColor = "#176faa"
$label1.AutoSize = $true
$label1.width = 25
$label1.height = 10
$label1_height = $Heigt_Form / 2.5
$label1_width = $Widht_Form / 2.2
$label1.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($label1_width,$label1_height)

$Title.Text = "Do you need handling the job?"
$Title.ForeColor = "#176faa"
$Title.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,16,style=Bold'
$Title.AutoSize = $true
$Title.width = 25
$Title.height = 10
$Title_height = $Heigt_Form / 5
$Title_width = $Widht_Form / 5
$Title.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($Title_width,$Title_height)

$Yes.AutoSize = $true
$Yes_height = $Heigt_Form * 0.7
$Yes_width = $Widht_Form / 8
$Yes.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($Yes_width,$Yes_height)
$Yes.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(90,35)
$Yes.Text = "Yes"
$Yes.Add_Click(
    {
    Write-Host "Call GUI Control"
    Start-Sleep -s 1
    $Form.Close()
    }
)

$No.AutoSize = $true
$No_height = $Heigt_Form * 0.7
$No_width = ($Yes_width * 6) - 35
$No.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($No_width,$No_height)
$No.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(90,35)
# $No.BackColor = "#9fd5f3"
$No.Text = "No"
$No.Add_Click(
    {
    Write-Host "Continue the process"
    $Form.Close()
    }
)

$timer1.add_Tick($timer1_Tick)
$Form.ResumeLayout()

#Save the initial state of the form
$InitialFormWindowState = $Form.WindowState
#Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
$Form.add_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
#Clean up the control events
$Form.add_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
#Show the Form
return $Form.ShowDialog()
```

I already try some function like autosize, but it's still the same problem.

Comment: You can try to use WPF instead of Winforms (WPF is much better at DPI scaling). Getting started with WPF is not easy though (but it is possible with PS to use a WPF XML file for the GUI and even stuff like 2 way databinding works - with some limitations)

Answer (score 0):

Look at Autoscale instead of Autosize.

```
$form.AutoScale = $true
```

I usually use the font mode and choose one of the system fonts

```
$form.AutoScaleMode = "Font"
```

You have to remember that the *apparent* size WILL change according to the monitor/resolution you use unelss you detect the current resolution and use a percentage of that for your form.

The easiest way is to just control the pixel size and scaling.

Comment: Oh and don't use a fixed style for the form (  $form1.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog")

Comment: The $form variable should match the one you;re using for your form ($form1)
It does work, I'm using it in my forms.

Comment: Hi @Scepticalist I already change the variable name. It does not return any error BUT the size is become bigger once I execute it in different resolution :(