# How to remove specific item include content in text file using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have a text file with this format.

```
Configuration
;
;   Authors: James
;   Created: 10/11/2018
;
;   Accepted

Name
    James
Class
    A2
Birthday
    1 September 1982
Family Member
    4
First Year Salary Number
    100 USD
Second Year Salary Number
    150 USD
Company Name
    Unlimited Company
Total Salary Number
    1300 USD
ExpectedSalaryNumber
    FY:350 USD
    SY:450 USD
    TS:2000 USD
```

I want to remove the whole content if the head contain of `"Salary Number"` and `"SalaryNumber"`, also remove the title `"Configuration.... "` and output the file after remove it. My expectation output file is like this

```
Name
    James
Class
    A2
Birthday
    1 September 1982
Family Member
    4
Company Name
    Unlimited Company
```

I tried this, but it just output the content that I remove.
Anyone can help me please.
Thank you so much.

```
$name = $false 
& { 
  switch -regex -file .\Configuration.TXT {
    '^*Salary Number*, ^*SalaryNumber*' { $name = $true; continue }
    '^\s' { if ($name) { $_.Trim() }}
    '^\S' { if ($name) { return } }
  }
} | Remove-Item | Out-File .\Output.txt
```

#### Updated Format File

```
ExpectedSalaryNumber
        FY:350 USD
        (White Space)
        SY:450 USD
        (White Space)
        TS:2000 USD
```

Comment: Sorry, had to delete my answer as it didn't work. `switch` isn't the right technique to use.

Comment: It's okay. I'm still struggle with this problem :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511772/read-file-line-by-line-in-powershell - Use this in combination with `Add-Content` to add lines to the final output file.

Comment: It different case I think :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example still uses `switch`, but this time it uses it to determine what to do with each line, after which it outputs only those lines of interest (non-salary, non-header):

```
# These variables are changed to true if the line is a header or a salary
$header = $false
$salary = $false
Get-Content .\Configuration.TXT | ForEach-Object {
    # The header flag is reset each time as the header checks are made first
    $header = $false
    # The $salary variable is only reset back to false when a new header is reached, provided it does not contain Salary\s*Number

    # Use switch to find out what type of line it is
    switch -regex ($_)
    {
        '^Configuration' # Beginning with Configuration 
        {
            $header = $true
        }
        '^;' # Beginning with semicolon 
        {
            $header = $true
        }
        # Data lines begin with a space
        # move to the next line - do not alter $salary variable
        '^\s'  
        {
            continue
        }
        # If Salary Number is found set the flag
        'Salary\s*Number' {
            $salary = $true
        }
        # This is only reached once it has been determined the line is 
        # not a header
        # not a salary header line
        # not a data line 
        # i.e. only headers that are not Salary
        # this resets the flag and makes lines eligible for output
        default {
            $salary = $false
        }

    }
    # Only output lines that are not Salary and not headers
    if ($salary -eq $false -and $header -eq $false) {
        $_
    }
} | Out-File .\Output.txt
```

Comment: I don't have a Windows computer to test this on at the moment, let me know if it works!

Comment: It return empty output file :(

Comment: That should now work, I wasn't resetting the `$header` variable each time. Do you follow how the code works?

Comment: Cheers - pretty tough without a computer to test it on! Could you accept the answer if you're happy with it. Added heaps of comments too to explain how it processes. I learnt how to use `switch` too, so we both gained something :)

Comment: Yes, I did. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Hi @mjsqu . I have one more problem with this question. If I have a format file like those (I put the format file above), it only remove the head, not include the content. If you don't mind can help me please. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, please start a new question.

Comment: Hi @mjsqu. I did it. Thank you. I can fixed it.
If you don't mind, please take a look to my other question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/58688974/11076819 . Thank you!